# Developing iphone app for a particular book

Tags: objective-c, iphone, database, uiwebview, ios8

I would like to begin work on an iPhone app that display a books content for reading.I am having around 100 html files as book content. The book content is also available online, and is fully open source, but I would like to make the content available locally. So my question is that What is the best way to go from online web content to locally stored iPhone readable content? Regardless of which approach I take,how do i integrate data in my app, as one html file contain multiple chapters and topics and i want to each topic separately in index,as the user click on topic on index it navigates to that topic, so i cannot store these html files locally and display these in UIWebView.
I am just looking for a point in the right direction. If there were any suggestions about the best method for me to get rolling on this, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't store it in HTML. XML is far more preferable.

Comment: Why assume I down voted you?

Comment: Ohk.Sry. Any suggestions or approach to follow.? @ScottMcGready

Comment: Yeah, XML files. Then display them in-app natively.

Comment: FYI, I reckon your app is likely to be rejected: `2.21
Apps that are simply a song or movie should be submitted to the iTunes store. Apps that are simply a book should be submitted to the iBooks Store`

Comment: I think he's going to build a book reader rather than just a single book. For the purposes of learning though, he can still build the app and use it locally

Comment: I Think @ScottMcGready is right.Like there are various religious book apps on AppStore which only show complete book with different UI.I want to develop same kinda app (religious). But confused about data integration.
 Sir should i generate XML files from HTML files m having.? or ua talking about something diff. Sry but m not getting it

Comment: Go and have a read up about how to display data from XML,DB etc. loads of tutorials around.

Answer (score 0):

sqllite is used to store data in db for mobile clients. You can populate it with data by sqlitebrowser. Then read tutorials about sqllite, how to integrate it with mobile app.

Good advantage of sqllite is that you can upgrade the scheme on the fly - no need to resubmit app, if no significant change to scheme were applied.

Comment: Storing screeds of text in SQLite might be problematic (hence the XML idea).